# AngularJS ng-submit not working on mobile

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, forms, mobile-browser

My form is working fine on desktop browser but not in mobile.

My HTML form is

```
<!-- Header Search Form -->
<div ng-show="true" style="background-color:black" class="header-search-form header-search-form--right">
    <form ng-submit="search(searchText)" id="mobile-search-form" data-ajax="false" class="search-form">
        <input type="text" ng-model="searchText" class="form-control header-mobile__search-control" value="" placeholder="Arama">
        <button type="submit" class="header-mobile__search-submit">
            <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
        </button>
    </form>
</div>
<!-- Header Search Form / End -->
```

It performs a search query.

In desktop browser it is working like this www.test.com/search/searchText

In mobile browser when I click the search button for submit the form it is giving www.test.com? and redirects to main page.

What should be the problem ?

EDIT:

This is my controller

```
$rootScope.hideNews = true;
        $scope.search_string = $routeParams.param1;
        $window.document.title = $scope.search_string + ' için arama sonuçları';

        $window.scrollTo(0, 0);

        var parseAPI = "xxx";
        var parse_app_id = "xxxxxxx";
        var parse_rest_api_key = "xxxxxxx";

        $scope.startLimit = 10;

        $scope.makeSearch = function (searchString) {
            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: parseAPI + "/WebNews",
                cache: true,
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'X-Parse-Application-Id': parse_app_id,
                    'X-Parse-REST-API-Key': parse_rest_api_key
                },
                params: {
                    where: {
                        'content_category_id': {
                            '$ne': 'gerter2312'
                        },
                        'text_content': { "$text": { "$search": { "$term": searchString } } }

                    },
                    limit: $scope.startLimit,
                    order: '-createdAt'
                }
            })
                .then(function (result) {
                    console.log(result);
                    $scope.searchResults = result.data.results;
                    if ($scope.searchResults.length <= 0) {
                        $scope.nullResult = true;
                    }
                }, function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                });
        };

        $scope.makeSearch($scope.search_string);

        $scope.loadMore = function () {
            $scope.startLimit += 10;
            $scope.makeSearch($scope.search_string);
        };
```

And my config for search page

```
.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/arama/:param1', {
            templateUrl: 'search/search.html',
            controller: 'searchCtrl'
        });
    }])
```

Comment: can you post what is in search controller

Comment: @Sajeetharan I edited question and added controller and config code

Comment: @SuatKarabacak have you solved this issue?

Comment: @PoltoS unfortunately I did not solve it.